# How to remove django-filter additional keywords in form fileld label

Tags: django, django-filters

When i customize search type in the filter:

```
django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
```

it adds *'[field_name] contains'* keyword to the end of displaying label in template `{{ field.label }}`. I specifically use `verbose_name='Some filed'` argument in my model to make it accessible in template, but filter modifies it for inexplicable reason.
Is there any option for it to be displayed as i set it in versbose_name?

UPD:
Solved this adding this to settings.py

```
 def FILTERS_VERBOSE_LOOKUPS():
    from django_filters.conf import DEFAULTS

    verbose_lookups = DEFAULTS['VERBOSE_LOOKUPS'].copy()
    verbose_lookups.update({
        'exact': (''),
        'iexact': (''),
        'contains': (''),
        'icontains': (''),
    })
    return verbose_lookups
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `label` parameter to the filter to explicitly set the field's label:

```
django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='the label')
```

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#label

Also, if you don't like the way django-filters creates its filters, you can play with the `FILTERS_VERBOSE_LOOKUPS` setting (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/settings.html#verbose-lookups-setting). I haven't tested it but it says that you can set it to `False` to disable this behavior - you may want to try this instead.

Comment: Nice, thanks, exactly what i was looking for. Solved it with FILTERS_VERBOSE_LOOKUPS.